# Generate dynamic controls by XML Parsing in Ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

Any Body help me.

I want to create one Dynamic view. In which i want to add dynamic controls. These controls are come from xml. And need to display in single view on click event of button.

My xml format is like as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><customer><cust type="101"><lable><1> customer name </1><2> customer phone </2><3> customer age </3><4> customer Birth </4></lable><value><1>textfield</1><2> textfield </2><3> textfield </3><4>Date</4></value></cust><cust type="102"><lable><1> customer qualification </1><2> customer Email</2></lable><value><1>textfield</1><2>Email</2></cust><cust type="103"><lable><1> customer name </1><2> customer phone </2><3> customer age </3><4> customer Birth </4></lable><value><1>textfield</1><2>textfield</2><3>textfield</3><4>Date</4></value></cust><cust type="104"><lable><1> customer qualification </1><2> customer Email</2><3> customer gender </3><4> customer Birth </4></lable><value><1>textfield</1><2>textfield</2><3>CheckBox</3><4>Date</4>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know how to make this but i think this may help you

[check this](https://github.com/jonathanellis/pegasus)

[and read about views (apple docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But this demo is not useful for me. Please give me  other solution. 
I am repeating my Question:
I have to display Controls like Check-Box, Pick List, Pick List with Multiple Select , Text view, Text Box etc dynamically as per the instructions coming from .net web service.
I need to parse xml, then read it and then display dynamically.
Any help regarding this will highly appreciable..
Thanks in advance once again. :-)

Comment: @Hiren If above answer is not helping you then why accept this answer?, only for increase your reputation or anything else?